# Looping through a 2-D list within a 1-D list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 2 lists:

- One dimensional: `x_int_loc = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`
- Two dimensional: `xtremes = [[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,8]]`

I am trying to gather a count of how many times each element in `x_int_loc` lies within the range of values in the `xtremes` list. That is, count of `1` (in list `x_int_loc`) will be `2`, as it appears in `[0,2]`, `[0,3]` and so on.

Although this appears to be quite simple, I got a bit stuck while looping through these lists. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(x_int_loc)):
    while k < len(xtremes):
        if x_int_loc[i]>xtremes[k][0] and xtremes[k][1] > x_int_loc[i]:
            count[i] = count[i]+1
print(count[:])
```

Could any of you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're going wrong? What output were you expecting, and what did you get? Where is `count` defined?

Comment: for x, y in xtremes:
    for z in x_int_loc:
        if z>=x && z<=y:
            print z +'is in range'

Comment: Thanks Jon! Count is defined at the top as a null list, sorry I didn't include that. I was expecting a list of count[], where the list consists of the number of times the element in x_int_loc appears in the "xtremes" list. So, something like this: [0,2,3,2,3,2], because 0 appears 0 times, 1 appears 2 times and so on. Hope I am making myself clear?

Comment: @user3792245 and what do you get instead?

Comment: I get a "list index out of range" error for i.

Comment: On what line? **Edit your question** to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) others can *actually run* (i.e. *including* the definition of `count`) and the *full error traceback*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never increment `k`, or reset it when `i` increments. The minimal fix is:

```
for i in range(len(x_int_loc)):
    k = 0
    while k < len(xtremes):
        if x_int_loc[i]>xtremes[k][0] and xtremes[k][1] > x_int_loc[i]:
            count[i] = count[i]+1
        k += 1
```

It is not good practice to use a `while` loop with a manual index; as this clearly demonstrates, it is error prone. Why not just `for` loop over `xtremes` directly? All you really need is:

```
count = [sum(x < n < y for x, y in xtremes) for n in x_int_loc]
```

which gives me:

```
>>> count
[0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: nice answer jon. I tried eluding to something like this in my comment :)

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms thank you! (I think you mean [alluding](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/allude_elude.htm)).

Comment: Great, thanks guys and oops, I missed bringing k back to 0 as well! :( Cheers! Sree.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You learn something new every day. xD Sadly it was too late to edit my mistake and will forever look unwise :(

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are too particular about optimization, in general cases, the following solution would be optimal

```
>>> x_int_loc = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> xtremes = [[0,2],[0,3],[1,3],[1,5],[2,5],[3,6],[4,8]]
>>> xtremes_ranges = [xrange(r[0]+1,r[1]) for r in xtremes]
>>> [(x, sum(x in r for r in xtremes_ranges)) for x in x_int_loc]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 2)]
```